# Hibernate soft delete queries return deleted grandchildren

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, soft-delete

In many cases in my application, I want to return a tree of data using @OneToMany and @ManyToOne relationships.  I am implementing soft delete using @SQLDelete
@Where annotations.  I cannot figure out how to keep the tree from returning soft deleted grandchild objects.

For example, my parent entity ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gson_test_parent")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE gson_test_parent SET deleted = true, deleted_at = now() WHERE id=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public class GsonTestParent extends SoftDeletableEntity {

    public static final String STATUS_NEW = "new";
    public static final String STATUS_ACTIVE = "active";
    public static final String STATUS_DISABLED = "disabled";

    @Expose
    private String name;

    @Expose
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="gsonTestParentId")
    private List<GsonTestParentToGsonTestChild> gsonTestParentToGsonTestChild = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<GsonTestParentToGsonTestChild> getGsonTestParentToGsonTestChild() {
        return gsonTestParentToGsonTestChild;
    }
}
```

... my join entity ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gson_test_parent_to_gson_test_child")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE gson_test_parent_to_gson_test_child SET deleted = true, deleted_at = now() WHERE id=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public class GsonTestParentToGsonTestChild extends SoftDeletableEntity {
    public static final String STATUS_ACTIVE = "active";
    public static final String STATUS_DISABLED = "disabled";

    @Expose
    private Long gsonTestParentId;

    @Expose
    @Transient
    @GsonExcludeBackReference
    private GsonTestParent gsonTestParent;

    @Expose
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Where(clause = "deleted=false")
    private GsonTestChild gsonTestChild;

    public Long getGsonTestParentId() {
        return gsonTestParentId;
    }

    public GsonTestParent getGsonTestParent() {
        return gsonTestParent;
    }

    public void setGsonTestParent(GsonTestParent gsonTestParent) {
        this.gsonTestParent = gsonTestParent;
    }

    public GsonTestChild getGsonTestChild() {
        return gsonTestChild;
    }
}
```

... and the child entity ...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "gson_test_child")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE gson_test_child SET deleted = true, deleted_at = now() WHERE id=?")
@Where(clause = "deleted=false")
public class GsonTestChild extends SoftDeletableEntity {

    public static final String STATUS_NEW = "new";
    public static final String STATUS_ACTIVE = "active";
    public static final String STATUS_DISABLED = "disabled";

    @Expose
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

FYI, these all extend SoftDeletableEntity, which looks like ...

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class SoftDeletableEntity extends BaseEntity {

    public SoftDeletableEntity() {
        super();
    }

    @Expose
    protected Timestamp deletedAt;

    protected Boolean deleted = Boolean.FALSE;

    public Timestamp getDeletedAt() {
        return deletedAt;
    }

    public void setDeletedAt(Timestamp deletedAt) {
        this.deletedAt = deletedAt;
    }

    public Boolean getDeleted() {
        return deleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(Boolean deleted) {
        this.deleted = deleted;
    }
}
```

When I do a find on the parent entity ...

```
@GetMapping(path="/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<String> get(@PathVariable Long id) throws BaseException {
    Map<String, Object> responseMap = new HashMap<>();

    GsonTestParent gsonTestParent = gsonTestParentService.find(id);
    responseMap.put("action", "Get");
    responseMap.put("message", "Entity retrieved");
    responseMap.put("entityType", "GsonTestParent");
    responseMap.put("entity", gsonTestParent);

    return responseService.success(responseMap);
}
```

I get the child entity (grandchild) even though it is marked as deleted in the database ...

```
{
  "payload": {
    "entityType": "GsonTestParent",
    "action": "Get",
    "message": "Entity retrieved",
    "entity": {
      "name": "test_parent_1",
      "gsonTestParentToGsonTestChild": [
        {
          "gsonTestParentId": 1,
          "gsonTestChild": {
            "name": "test_child_1",
            "deletedAt": "2022-07-26T04:31:30.000",
            "id": 1,
            "createdAt": "2022-07-22T07:24:15.000",
            "updatedAt": "2022-07-22T07:24:15.000",
            "status": "active"
          },
          "deletedAt": null,
          "id": 1,
          "createdAt": "2022-07-22T07:57:46.000",
          "updatedAt": "2022-07-22T07:57:46.000",
          "status": "active"
        }
      ],
      "deletedAt": null,
      "id": 1,
      "createdAt": "2022-07-22T07:23:15.000",
      "updatedAt": "2022-07-22T07:23:15.000",
      "status": "active"
    }
  },
  "status": "success"
}
```

The gson_test_child record in the DB

```
mysql> select * from gson_test_child where id = 1;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+--------------+
| id | created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at          | deleted | status | name         |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+--------------+
|  1 | 2022-07-22 14:24:15 | 2022-07-22 14:24:15 | 2022-07-26 11:31:30 |       1 | active | test_child_1 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+--------------+
```

A few comments:

- I am referencing the join table explicitly, as opposed to using the @JoinTable functionality because many of the "join" tables in my app have other meaningful fields I want to expose.
- I thought the @Where annotation on the GsonTestParentToGsonTestChild.gsonTestChild field would eliminate soft deleted children, but apparently not (or I'm doing something wrong).
- I know I can create explicit JOIN FETCH native queries in the repositories that will filter the deleted grandchildren, but that kind of subverts the reasons for using annotations.

Please let me know if I can provide further information.
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@Where(clause = "deleted=false")` also to the collections.

Answer (score 0):

@Christian Beikov,

it looks like you're correct.  The `@Where(clause = "deleted=false")` works on an @OneToMany relationship, but not on an @ManyToOne.

Answer (score 0):

`@Where(clause = "is_deleted = false")` is deprecated. You can use `@SQLRestriction(value = "is_deleted = false")` instead.